# Listar Atributos de um Elemento HTML com JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fala galera, tudo em paz?

Estava procurando uma solução na internet, porém não encontrei o que eu precisava, nem compreendi uma forma de fazer, se alguém puder me dar uma luz?

Gostaria de listar os atributos de um elemento, usando `Jquery`, por exemplo esse `input`:

```
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="class1">
```

E a saída seria:

```
object{
    type: "text",
    name: "input1",
    id: "input1",
    class: "class1"
}
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar o [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) que te dá um objeto iterável com nodes onde podes extrair a chave e valor de cada propriedade.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input1');
const attributes = {};
for (let attr of input.attributes) {
  attributes[attr.name] = attr.value; 
}

console.log(attributes) // {type:"text",name:"input1",id:"input1",class:"class1"}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="class1">
```

Answer (score 2):

Com jQuery você pode estender a função do método `.attr()` para retornar todos os atributos de um elemento:

```js
(function(e){
   $.fn.attr = function(){
      if(!arguments.length){
         if(!this.length) return null;

         var obj = {};
         $.each(this[0].attributes, function(){
            if(this.specified) obj[this.name] = this.value;
         });
         return obj;
      }

      return e.apply(this, arguments);
   }
})($.fn.attr);

var atributos = $("#input1").attr();

console.log(atributos);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="class1">
```

Comment: Sugiro usar `attrs`, no plural, é mais semântico.

Comment: Seria uma ótima ideia tb.